# Equation of a 2D parabola in 3D, and proving that the projection on to basis planes are also parabolas

Tags: conic-sections, 3d, parametric, projective-geometry

If I have three **collinear** points in the $x$-$y$ plane, $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$, and each has an associated point in the $z$ direction, how do I derive the equation for a parabola that passes through each of the $z$ points?

Also, is there any way to prove that if the parabola was projected on to the $x$-$z$ or $y$-$z$ planes, that the resulting curve would *also* be a parabola (I have a feeling it would be)?

[image: 1D3DParab]

Comment: How is it a $1$-D parabola? Isn't it a $2$-D parabola?

Comment: Good point, I'll try to edit

Comment: If you move about your axes about you will find that it is simply a normal parabola with $z = 0$.

Comment: And yes it should also be a parabola as all you are doing is shifting the axes.

Comment: $z=0$? Then I would just have the three points in the $x-y$ plane they are collinear... Do you mean rotating about $z$-axis?

Comment: Well by shifting I meant translation and rotation. Actually it should be $x-z$ plane and $y-z$ plane for only translation. But I said $x-y$ as it is **way** more common.

Comment: I think you can find the equation of the parabola in the $x - z$ plane and find the new equation after rotating the axes.

Comment: Surely, the curve you get by rotating about the $z$ axis until the parabola lines up with one of the basis planes is different from the curve you get by projecting the original curve on to the basis planes... The rotation preserves the curvature while projection would produce a different curvature.

Comment: Point but if you add stretching to the list of operations you can produce exactly what you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoh4TmPzu1w

Comment: What sort of equation are you looking for? A curve in 3-D can’t be described by a single implicit equation as can a curve in 2-D. You’ll need to either have a system of implicit equations, giving this curve as the intersection of two surfaces, or have a parametric equation.

Comment: Also, three points are not enough to define a parabola uniquely. Are there other constraints, such as having its axis parallel to the $z$-axis, perhaps?

Comment: The projections are affine transformations. The affine image of a parabola is another parabola.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the question what kind of equation is expected. If $y=mx+q$ is the equation of the line in the $x-y$ plane, I think the most natural way to handle such a parabola is that of finding the equation of its projection on the $x-z$ plane, which is a parabola of equation
$$
\tag{1}
z=ax^2+bx+c.
$$
You can find $a$, $b$ and $c$, as usual, by plugging there the coordinates of the three given points: only $x$ and $z$ are needed, because $y=mx+q$.

In other words: the parabola is the intersection between the parabolic cylinder given by equation $(1)$ and the plane of equation $y=mx+q$.

If the line in the $x-y$ plane is parallel to the $y$ axis then you can instead project the parabola onto the $y-z$ plane.

Comment: The equation of the curve through 3-space is what I was looking for for the first part of the question

Comment: How do we *know* that the projection on to the x-z plane will be a parabola?

Comment: Watch this youtube.com/watch?v=hoh4TmPzu1w

Comment: @D.W. We know because you can imagine your parabola as the intersection of the parabolic cylinder $z=ax^2+bx+c$ with plane $y=mx+q$. The intersection of a quadric with a plane is a conic, which in the case at hand is not limited and is made of a single piece, hence a parabola.